# Browsable Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

How to restrict user to open specific extension file only in browsable intent android?

we have list of diff files with diff extension in external storage..From that we want our application name in **20170601_abc** file's open with list.
Currently we used browsable intent for that and we have used following path pattern for that.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="..*/.*_abc" />
</intent-filter>
```

but by using this,we found our application list in all file's open with list. but we want our application's name in openwith list of such file whose name ends with  _abc

Comment: This `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />` means **all** file types. You should restrict the MIME type to the type you want to list.

Comment: mean?..If I want to open 20170601_abc file then what MIME type should i use?

Comment: Do you know **what kind of file** is this `20170601_abc` you mentioned?

Comment: Actually, there is no any file extension on that file. so MIME type is null on that file. i want to open without extension file with the use of pathpattern.

Comment: Then don't be surprised that **all** MIME types are displayed, if you don't want to set a specific one. Your app, like you isn't going to **guess** which could be the right app to open your file with.